# install ubuntu on a pc with windows 8(had XP before upgrading to 8) directly making it a dual boot?

Tags: server

I expected much from the new windows 8. Sadly it sucks. Now i want to install ubuntu server edition...should i uninstall win 8 first, the install XP, and the install Ubuntu as a dual boot?

OR,

Should i directly install ubuntu with win 8 as a dual boot?

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what you use your computer for... gaming, office work, etc.  While XP is one of the better Windows versions it can be rather old when running newer games but will dual boot quite happily with Ubuntu...  Windows 8 on the other hand will run newer games ok but somehow has a lot of quirks running older one's that XP can handle...  Then there's an Ubuntu only installation which will run mostly everything with the new WINE installed so it can run windows software, but not everything will run...

Let us know what you'll be doing on your computer so we can advise...

Here's a link just-in-case: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

Comment: i am designing a text based game( called MUDs). The coding will be done using a software which works best with ubuntu. (I don't play any games because i am not a good gamer)

Comment: The thing is that i have heard that windows 8 has this feature called secure boot which does not allow any other operating system on the computer

Comment: anyways my comp had XP before and then i have 8, so will the secure boot still apply in my case?

Comment: Windows 8's secure boot needs a UEFI enabled computer to work properly and thankfully the new Ubuntu supports UEFI no problem and can happily dual boot with Windows 8 using the guide link I posted above...  If you are using Ubuntu mostly for all of your work though inc. the text based game then that's all I would have on your computer, Ubuntu...